# Difficult structure definition in firebase for setting up data

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

[image]

**UPDATE:**
So basically this is my firebase structure and I edited users collection to have a special list called ListaFavorite that brings up all the favorite items users will add in his session. The problem is , i have to define in the original UserInterface file the exact same structure as in the firebase.

The favoriteObj i declared stores values from the item fields and brings them up to the firebase , but how i can set structure to the favoriteObj since i can't use objects in interface?

Sorry if I didn't made myself clear , but this is basically all i want.

I'm trying to match my structure that is:

```
 const favoriteObj = {};
    favoriteObj[uniqID] = {
      favorite_title: favorite_title,
      favorite_description: favorite_description,
      favorite_image: favorite_image,
      favorite_tag: favorite_tag,
      favorite_stoc: favorite_stoc,
      favorite_reducere: favorite_reducere,
      favorite_price: favorite_price,
      favorite_userId: favorite_userId,
      isFavorite: true,
    };
```

to my User interface from firebase that is :

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  FavoriteID: string;
  SavedFavorite: boolean;
  AddCosID: string;
  SavedCos: boolean;
  ListaFavorite: ... // here i must pass the favoriteObj
}
```

After that I must include in the function to update data :

```
SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afStore.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );

    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      FavoriteID: null,
      SavedFavorite: null,
      AddCosID: null,
      SavedCos: null,
      ListaFavorite : ...
    };
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true,
    });
  }
```

My point is to mark the favorite objects into the current user interface and then call all the objects according to the user logged in it's favorite page.
I don't really know how to pass the obj there. Any help ??

Comment: Try simplying your code and provide a minimal working example. If you dont put effort into preparing your question, don't expect anyone to do it for an answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer! I updated my question. This is all i can show you that may help you.. I don't have any working example since this is the last stage where i can't run my program.

Answer (score 0):

to add object to an interface you will need to do what's called nested interfaces. you should create an interface for favoriteObj:

```
interface FavoriteObj {
      favorite_title: string,
      favorite_description: string,
      favorite_image: string,
      ...
}
```

then nested it in the user interface using `[key: string]` which is what we call [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  FavoriteID: string;
  SavedFavorite: boolean;
  AddCosID: string;
  SavedCos: boolean;
  ListaFavorite: {
       [key: string]: FavoriteObj
  }
}
```